# How do I deploy an org-level lightning record page (flexipage) assignment through packaging?

Tags: salesforcedx, flexipages, lightning-record-page

We have a standard object (Quotes) with a custom lightning record page (flexipage) assigned at an **org-level**. I'm not sure what's triggering it, but recently when we do deployments related to quotes, the org-level record page assignment keeps getting reset to the system default instead.

We have been setting this manually in each org (sandbox/production), but is there a piece of metadata that org level assignments get set at? I know there's the CustomApplication option, where we assign it at an app level, which is our alternative, but if we can get it set at the org level and keep it, that'd be ideal.

Comment: It should be in the object definition for org level override. https://albasfdc.com/2018/09/09/lightning-pages-and-managed-packages/

Comment: Thank you! That was what I needed. I did a retrieve from my sandbox and it automatically pulled in the org level setting at the object level. I just needed to know where to look! Thanks again. Would you post this as an answer so I can mark it solved and also give you appropriate credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be in the object definition for org level override.

If you need more details, you can have a look here.  https://albasfdc.com/2018/09/09/lightning-pages-and-managed-packages/

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @manjit5190 answer, this is what the XML snippet looks like for the Custom Object (I used `Lead`) with Lightning Record page `Lead_B2B`

The first `actionOverrides` is for the desktop form factor, the latter for phone. Note the `<type>Flexipage</type>` which tells you it is a Lightning Page.

[Metadata API doc ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/actionoverride.htm#actionoverride)

```
  ...
  <actionOverrides>
    <actionName>View</actionName>
    <comment>Action override created by Lightning App Builder during activation.</comment>
    <content>Lead_B2B</content>
    <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
    <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
    <type>Flexipage</type>
  </actionOverrides>

  <actionOverrides>
    <actionName>View</actionName>
    <comment>Action override created by Lightning App Builder during activation.</comment>
    <content>Lead_B2B</content>
    <formFactor>Small</formFactor>
    <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
    <type>Flexipage</type>
  </actionOverrides>
  ...
```